# Sinch unanswered call timeout

Tags: timeout, sinch

The length before an unanswered call ends with the "timeout" state seems to be 45 seconds.

Can this be adjusted anywhere within the JS or Android api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the SDKs, but if you mail me I change it in the config for you. 45 is the standard so the call might be ended further down the line if we are talking about app to PSTN

Comment: If it is app to app calling in iOS then we can decrease time or not?